# When I create a Share Point Application and Press f5 in VS for SharePoint and click On trust it it gives me error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, iis-8, sharepoint-workflow

I am making an on premise SharePoint application.
Things I have done:

1. Certificate pfx I have created and can see in Web.config File.
2. DNS Set Properly.
   On Deploy the application-->SharePoint application comes and when i click on trust it-->Than it comes with error message ::

> This page can’t be displayed
>
> Make sure the web address https://localhost:44300 is correct.
>
> Look for the page with your search engine.
>
> Refresh the page in a few minutes

Thanks In Advance Guys

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy SharePoint Solution on this way:

- Right click the solution
- Click Deploy
- After successfully deployed, check it to SharePoint site.

Comment: What I did Ronak I-->I right click on the solution and selected deploy.It takes 1 min and than browser opened and than when I clicked on certificate trust it.It comes with the same error message. I think I made the certificate wrong but than I followed exactly the same  like below has been followed to make a ssl certificate https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Any tutorial will seriously help me Ronak to trust the application in the browser and it shows me the next page.If you do have any link please share with me.

Comment: I have publish the the sharepoint project got a app file than-->Added .app file in app calalog and clicked on site contents.My application was there and than I clicked it says The specified application identifier * is invalid or does not exist. .....But what I have noticed is that when I made some demo project which I can see their when i click on it they get added in my (Your apps) and on click on trust it some apps works some not...

Comment: Am I putting wrong Client and Secret ID in Visual Studio File is that so Ranak why The specified application identifier * is invalid or does not exist   this error message comes any idea.

Comment: I  detail this error message comes.. any Idea Ronak.I have set a new client id and secret id of the app and addes to webconfir,element.xml and sharepoint application at the time of publish.. error is like that.                        
Sorry, something went wrong 









The specified application identifier bf26f376-ff4a-4625-9b4f-8089a65b512c is invalid or does not exist. 



Technical Details 
 


 



Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 


Correlation ID: 87d7819d-8fca-509f-fa04-e0a9e56ea212 

Date and Time: 6/1/2016 2:59:14 PM

Comment: Choose patterns for developing and hosting your SharePoint Add-in - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179887%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I am making a Provide hosted application and making an provide hosted application which is to be hosted on the companies server

Comment: can I have your Number please... Please mail me gera_basant@yahoo.com    I need some help dude.

Comment: I think it will be better if you ask your question here in separate sharepoint stackexchange site >> http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/   ...you will get the answer from most experience sharepoint developers there..